# OpenCV segmentation fault after comparing descriptor.type and descriptor.cols

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, feature-detection

In my program whenever I cover the camera with something that causes no ORB features to be detected the program crashes with the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)) in batchDistance, file /bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 2473
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:2473: error: (-215) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function batchDistance

Aborted
```

In order to try and fix this error I followed the advice in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650371/matcher-assertions-failed-error-opencv-android) which involved adding the following `if` around the line `matcher->match(descriptorsObject, descriptors, matches);`

```
 if(descriptorsObject.type() == descriptors.type() && descriptorsObject.cols == descriptors.cols) {
      matcher->match(descriptorsObject, descriptors, matches);
  }
```

However when the camera cannot detect any feature points the program still crashes but I just get the error:

`Segmentation fault`

I am not sure why this is now happening, do I need to have an `else` condition to get the next frame if the condition of the `if` is not met?

EDIT:
When the code is run in debug mode I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402d9e in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe428) at ORB.cpp:57
57        double dist = matches[i].distance;
```

When enabling all warnings when compiling I get the following:

```
ORB.cpp:87:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

Extra code:

```
    if(descriptorsObject.type() == descriptors.type() && descriptorsObject.cols == descriptors.cols) {
      matcher->match(descriptorsObject, descriptors, matches);
    }

    double max_dist = 0;
    double min_dist = 100;
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptorsObject.rows; i++ ) { 
      double dist = matches[i].distance;  //LINE 57
      if( dist < min_dist ) 
        min_dist = dist;
      if( dist > max_dist ) 
       max_dist = dist;
    }
    std::vector<DMatch> goodMatches;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptorsObject.rows; i++ ) { 
      if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist ) { 
       goodMatches.push_back( matches[i]); 
      }
    }
if(goodMatches.size() >= 4) {
    Mat outputImage;
    Scalar keypointColor = Scalar(255, 0, 0);
    drawMatches( img_object, keypointsObject, gray, keypoints, goodMatches, imgMatches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    for( int i = 0; i < goodMatches.size(); i++ ) {  //LINE 87
      //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
      obj.push_back( keypointsObject[ goodMatches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
      scene.push_back( keypoints[ goodMatches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
    }
    std::vector<uchar> mask;
    Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC, 3, mask );
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, img_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, img_object.rows );
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
    line( imgMatches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( imgMatches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( imgMatches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    line( imgMatches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
    if (mask.size() < 100) {
      std::cout << fileNamePostCut << std::endl;
    }
}
    namedWindow("Output");
    imshow("Output", imgMatches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try debugging?

As modifying the code with the `if` statement led to a different error, the most possible reason could be that you might be trying to pick some value from `matches` or `descriptors` after the if condition. And as there are no matches or features present in the image, this can lead to segmentation fault.

Try debugging the code and give us more details including code snippet so that the possibilities could be narrowed down further.

Comment: I've added some additional information including an interesting warning during compilation (I've marked the line referenced in the code I've posted).

Comment: Using `matches.size()` instead of `descriptorsObject.rows` in line56 and line 65 would have solved the issue.

Comment: That resulted in the error: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type()) in findHomography, file bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 1074
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /bin/opencv-2.4.7/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:1074: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type() in function findHomography

Aborted
`

Comment: Those parts of the code is to be moved into `if(goodMatches.size() >= 4)` portion of the code. The main reason of this particular `if` condition is to check whether the minimum required number of points are present for `findHomography` function

Answer (score 0):

I extended the scope of the `if` statement so instead of closing after the line `matcher->match(descriptorsObject, descriptors, matches);` it now closes at the end above the line `namedWindow("Output");`